# A question about memory address in microcontroller vs PC

Tags: microcontroller, c, register

In context of embedded C, considering the following line:

```
*((volatile uint32_t *) 0x48000414) |= 1UL<<12;
```

Now 0x48000414 can be a memory pointer to a hardware register of a memory mapped microcontroller. So the above code tells: Go to the register at the address 0x48000414 and treat the register as if it is 32-bit wide and perform bitwise operation. So we can say that the address 0x48000414 in this case represents the address of a hardware register.

But when it comes to compiling this code for PC I cannot interpret what is happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    
    *((volatile uint32_t *) 0x48000414) |= 1UL<<12;

    return 0;
}
```

I use https://www.onlinegdb.com/ online C compiler and get no errors for the above code. But my question is what does 0x48000414 represent in this case?

Comment: This is really a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) question. Everything microcontroller-related in the question is only for context - the actual question is about the behavior of a PC, and will depend on the OS and how memory is managed, etc..

Comment: It represents a memory address, or an address of a memory mapped peripheral, just like in microcontroller. Likely an invalid one and your code has no right to access it. It will lead to undefined behavior (probably a crash).

Comment: OnlineGDB isn't quite representative of a regular PC in this case. It somewhat looks like it works (Says Program finished with exit code 0), but try doing something after that memory write, or run it with debugger. The program exits with segfault, which is pretty typical when you try to access memory that you are not allowed to under most operating systems.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is it possible to access after modifying? In this case The bitwise is 1UL<<12; But is there a way to dereference and access the variable at that memory? Or that is not possibe?

Comment: Depends where this address is pointing to, there is no way to know in general. Accessing invalid memory addresses leads to undefined behavior (crash, no visible effects, nuclear missile deployment, [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does 0x48000414 represent in this case?

Why do you expect it to "represent" anything different?

The compiled version of a C program is expected to run with respect to a [*virtual address space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Each variable in the program is stored at a unique address within that space.

Some particular microcontroller *hardware* might understand the address `0x48000414` to refer to a certain functional register, but the compiler doesn't need to know that. The compiler only needs to emit code that will fetch and store values from and to that address.

On some other hardware and operating system, that might just be a location in RAM, or it might be an invalid address, or it might be a read-only addres and the program will "segfault" when it's run. It might simply be an undefined address, where reading from it gives an unspecified value, and writing to it does nothing. Whichever it means though, the compiler doesn't know or care.

Comment: Can we access the variable after the bitwise operation  by  this syntax: *(0x48000414)  ? Or we can never access it?

Comment: @user1999 you can answer that yourself by running a test

Comment: @jsotola To be fair, relying on experiment results when dealing with undefined behavior is not a good idea. The right answer is *"do not even try"*.

Comment: @user1999, Again, the compiler doesn't know or care. You can use `*((volatile uint32_t *) 0x48000414)` as a left-hand (store) or a right-hand (fetch) expression, and the compiler will emit code to store or fetch from that address. What happens when the program runs will depend on the hardware and OS (if any) that are running it. Could access RAM, could cause a fault or trap, could do nothing, could cause some peripheral to perform some action, etc.

Answer (score 2):

On a PC, you're usually running your software with *virtual memory* (unless you're writing the early part of an operating system, or a hardware driver in that operating system, in which case you might still have *virtual* or *linear addresses*), so the address you use in a program has absolutely nothing (nothing!) to do with how hardware is mapped to memory addresses.

This is not operating system code, because there's `stdio.h`, which pretty much says you've already got an underlying operating system who is in charge of abstracted IO, and you're dealing with a `main` that returns something (where, if this is not a process run by an operating system?). (There's bare metal stdio implementations, I'm sure, even for x86, but this really looks like you're just writing userland code.)

There's a layer of address indirection, which maps pages of virtual memory to physical addresses. That mapping is pretty much arbitrary.

So,

> But my question is what does 0x48000414 represent in this case?

Nothing. A random address, which quite likely isn't even mapped to anything in your process, so that your operating system will gladly tell you to go and die due to a segmentation violation. If it *is* mapped, or if your program *handled* the fault raised by the violation, it would still be completely undefined what this address maps to.

Comment: Lots of bare metal libs implement stdio.h through a UART driver. That being said, stdio.h shouldn't be used in embedded systems (or elsewhere), but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Same code accesses same memory address on PC and microcontroller.

The problem at that memory address, there could be something or not.

And what happens is system dependent. On MCU that address might contain some peripheral. Or memory. Or nothing.

Same with PC, but likely an operating system with memory protection features would halt your program if it detects a read or write to a memory area which does not exist or contains something that needs to be protected from the user program making invalid memory accesses.